# Check field on parent page in TMENU?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

In a TMENU, can I check the value of a field on the parent page?

I want to do something like this:

```
lib.mymenu = HMENU
lib.mymenu {
  entryLevel=0
  1 = TMENU
  1 {
    ...
  }
  2 < .1
  2 {
    NO {
      stdWrap.wrap {
        if.equals.field = parent:myfield
        if.value = 1
        cObject < lib.specialmenu
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does the parent mean the item of the first level in this case? Or in other words: a field in the record which UID is the PID of the current item?

Then, there's a (german) blogpost on how to get dynamically fields via stdWrap:
https://blog.marit.ag/2009/12/15/datenbankfelder-stdwrap-data/

Comment: Looks like I might be able to do something like `if.equals.field.data = DB: pages: {field:pid}: myfield` I'll have to trial it.

Answer (score 0):

guess you have to implement a custom menuprocessor, or try at least a fluid version of your menu. in plain typoscript i dont know a solution for this.
this link may help you for my suggestion: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-sitepackage/master/en-us/MainMenuCreation/Index.html

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping to avoid remaking the whole thing in fluid, but if that's the only option...